# Social Network alternative to Telegram

Tags: android, ios, api, social-networks

Telegram is great. But in my country it's in the risk of being blocked. Is there any other social networking platform that:

```
* is free
* has API
* can be automated (bots)
* supports sending voice and image
* has many clients
```

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly my area of expertise, but have you checked WisperSystem's *Signal?* Currently available for Android and [Desktop](https://whispersystems.org/blog/signal-desktop/), an iOS app is "in the works". Not sure whether it fits all your requirements, though (especially concerning the voice and bots parts).

Comment: Signal seems a nice app, but I couldn't find API on it. API and automation is what makes telegram unique. I don't need privacy.

Comment: What "social" features do you need? Friending? Following? Groups?

Comment: What should the API be able to do? Everything?

Comment: Do you need end-to-end encryption?

Comment: API should be similar to whar the app does. Sending photos, text, audio, etc. I do not need end-to-end encryption. And I don't need any social ability. I just want the app to act as a free messaging infrastructure.

Comment: In that case, some Jabber/XMPP solutions might fit in.